# Is there a way to pass variables from a libgdx fragment to android activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, libgdx

I'm new to using libgdx but am looking for a way to pass variables from my libgdx game class to my main android activity. At the moment my libgdx game is displayed as a fragment in the main activity but I can't pass any variable without getting a NullPointerException. Is there a workaround for this without using Intent?

Comment: Same as with any Fragment and Activity, with or without libGDX. You can use `(activity as? MyActivity)?.doSomething(myObject)`. Or in Java: `if (getActivity() != null) ((MyActivity)getActivity()).doSomething(myObject);`. If you are triggering this from a game, make sure you put this code in a `post` call so it's run on the UI thread rather than the game thread.

Comment: Please add an example to your error, people can help you from there